# jquery ui tabs not showing any content except for first tab

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, tabs

I have a set of tabs and in each tab is a div with a few sub divs. The .tabs() call creates
the Tab headings and displays the first div ...

Clicking on second tab ... "Background" doesn't show its  despite being the same
as the div under the first tab ... which works.

Here is a js fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/GeoffRussell/cy6uL41d/

```
<div id="tabset">
    <ul> 
        <li><a href="#policytab">Policy</a></li>
        <li><a href="#backgroundtab">Background</a></li>
    </ul>
<div id="policytab">
    <div class="panel cflex">
        <div class="textdiv" contenteditable="true">xx</div>
        <div>
            <div class="lrflex">
            <div>L1</div>
            <div class="rflex">
                <div>R1</div>
                <div>R2</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="backgroundtab">
    <div class="panel cflex">
        <div class="textdiv" contenteditable="true">xx</div>
        <div>
            <div class="lrflex">
            <div>L1</div>
            <div class="rflex">
                <div>R1</div>
                <div>R2</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

With CSS as follows

```
.panel {
    height: 200px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    resize: both;
    overflow: auto;
}
.textdiv {
    border: 1px solid red;
    height: 1500px;
    overflow: auto;
}
.cflex {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
.rflex {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: flex-end;
    border: 1px solid purple;
}
.lrflex {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: flex-end;
    justify-content: space-between;
    border: 1px solid green;
}
```

With the action being ...

```
$("#tabset").tabs();
```

Comment: Well if you did inspect your code you would notice that you are missing 2 x `</div>` try this https://jsfiddle.net/uxdwbvto/'

Comment: Yes...user error ... div blindness! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Seems my extra level of  prior to the class="lrflex" div caused the
problem .... but I don't know why.

Answer (score 0):

I think your tab is working fine but your content text is same, that why not showing tabs result. so i quest to you change content and check again.